# can't access text of dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this should work so don't have a clue why it's not.

I am appending the data to the DOM from the ajax success callback and then accessing parts of the newly appended DOM but it's coming back blank with no errors:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(data).insertAfter('h1');
},
complete: function(data) {
    var serverlat = $('.pop-lat').text();
    var serverlng = $('.pop-lng').text();

    alert(serverlat + ',' + serverlng); // ' , '
}
```

**markup returned via ajax**

```
<div class="pop-lat">55.8613148</div>
<div class="pop-lng">-4.2676099</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `complete()` callback isn't called before your `success` one? Would explain everything

Comment: Are you sure your ajax call does'nt fail, as the complete handler is called either way, but the success handler is not !

Comment: complete is always called after success/error here the link to read it http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: did you console.log the data in success func.

Comment: try a dummy alert or console.log in success and tpo debug  if data is coming or not

Comment: ajax call definitely works as intended, dummy alert is blank, tried to show that in the question but it's not very obvious. Will try a console log but I'm not expecting anything different...

Comment: You don't have more than one `.pop-lat` and `.pop-lng` on the page, I hope? `.text()` will only return the contents of the first such element.

Comment: yip, only one. console log just gives the markup I am already adding to the page

Comment: At this point, we'd have to see a more complete block of code and/or the actual page to try and determine what's wrong.

Comment: this is the link: http://www.4playtheband.co.uk/fluency/ I will try and update the question with some more relevant code

Comment: Do you have any `h1` on page?

Comment: yep, h1 is there and markup returned from server is definitely added to the dom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your complete code in the `success` callback looks like this :

```
if (data != 0) {
    $('#enquiry-form').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        // animation has completed so append quotation form
        $(data).insertAfter('h1');
    });

} else {
    // spam form submission
    alert('error');
}
```

You're only appending the data once the animation has completed, and by that time the `complete` callback has already been executed, and your data was'nt there.

You'll need to change that to :

```
if (data != 0) {
    var $data = $(data)
    $data.insertAfter('h1').hide();

    $('#enquiry-form').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $data.show();
    });

} else {
    // spam form submission
    alert('error');
}
```

making sure it's in the DOM, but just hiding it until the animation has completed.

Comment: Ahhh, I knew we weren't getting the complete picture. ;-)

Comment: well spotted, thank you. I didn't think that would make a difference, apologies for not giving the 'complete picture', I try to only include relevant code in my questions but in this case I got it wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You are using **jQuery 1.10.x** where success method are `deprecated`:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

So lets try something this:

```
$.ajax({
    //your code here but without success and complete!!
}).done(function(data) {
    var data = $(data).insertAfter('h1');
    var serverlat = data.find('.pop-lat').text();
    var serverlng = data.find('.pop-lng').text();

    alert(serverlat + ',' + serverlng); // ' , '
})
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I'd read about that but didn't know what the new function was

Comment: Hint for you. Always look on documentation. Specially if you start using newest version of jQuery.

Comment: deprecated, but not removed, so it would still work, however +1 as moving on to `done()`, `fail()` and `always()` is a good idea.

Comment: It's still worked yes, but imagine situation when someone use cdn and latest version of jQuery. After one of next release jQuery he can lost some logic on page ;)